# Save associated data with cakephp 3

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm facing a problem trying patch an entity. My `$this->request->data` looks like this:

```
array:15 [▼
  "tipo_unidade_id" => "1"
  "sistemas" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▶]
    1 => array:1 [▼
      "id" => "1"
    ]
  ]
  "localidades" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "id" => "2"
    ]
  ]
  "status" => "1"
]
```

But after I patch the entity (`$unidade = $this->Unidades->patchEntity($unidade, $this->request->data);`), I get an odd behavior: The "sistemas" array looks OK, but the contents of the "localidades" array isn't patched. Below is a dump of my $unidade:

```
Unidade {#115 ▼
  +"tipo_unidade_id": 1
  +"sistemas": array:2 [▼
    0 => Sistema {#193 ▼
      +"id": 5
      +"status": true
      +"nome": "novoSissstema"
      +"created": Time {#191 ▶}
      +"modified": Time {#192 ▶}
      +"[new]": false
      +"[accessible]": array:1 [▶]
      +"[dirty]": []
      +"[original]": []
      +"[virtual]": []
      +"[errors]": []
      +"[repository]": "Sistemas"
    }
    1 => Sistema {#190 ▶}
  ]
  +"localidades": array:1 [▼
    0 => Localidade {#173 ▼
      +"[new]": true
      +"[accessible]": array:1 [▶]
      +"[dirty]": []
      +"[original]": []
      +"[virtual]": []
      +"[errors]": array:3 [▼
        "id" => array:1 [▼
          "unique" => "The provided value is invalid"
        ]
        "status" => array:1 [▼
          "_required" => "This field is required"
        ]
        "nome" => array:1 [▼
          "_required" => "This field is required"
        ]
      ]
      +"[repository]": "Localidades"
    }
  ]
  +"status": true
  +"[new]": true
  +"[accessible]": array:1 [▶]
  +"[dirty]": array:10 [▶]
  +"[original]": []
  +"[virtual]": []
  +"[errors]": []
  +"[repository]": "Unidades"
}
```

So my "sistemas" are being patched nicelly, but not my "localidades". They both look similar in my table classes. Here is a piece of my UnidadesTable.php file:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Localidades', [
            'foreignKey' => 'unidade_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'localidade_id',
            'joinTable' => 'localidades_unidades'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Sistemas', [
            'foreignKey' => 'unidade_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'sistema_id',
            'joinTable' => 'sistemas_unidades'
        ]);
```

They're basically the same type of association (has and belongs to many, both with intermediary tables, containing an id and both foreign keys). So why are they behaving differently? How can I debug this?

Almost forgot: This is part of my model: 
[image: my model]

Thanks in advance =]

edited: There follows my SistemasTable and LocalidadesTable files:

```
class SistemasTable extends Table
{
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('sistemas');
    $this->displayField('nome');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->hasMany('Mapas', [
        'foreignKey' => 'sistema_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsToMany('Unidades', [
        'foreignKey' => 'sistema_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'unidade_id',
        'joinTable' => 'sistemas_unidades'
    ]);
}
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create')
        ->add('id', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table']);

    $validator
        ->add('status', 'valid', ['rule' => 'boolean'])
        ->requirePresence('status', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('status');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('nome', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('nome');

    return $validator;
}
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['id']));
    return $rules;
}
```

LocalidadesTable.php

```
class LocalidadesTable extends Table
{
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('localidades');
    $this->displayField('nome');
    $this->primaryKey(['id']);

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Municipios', [
        'foreignKey' => 'municipio_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    //edited at 20160203 - 07:03 GMT-3
    $this->belongsToMany('Unidades', [
        'foreignKey' => 'localidade_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'unidade_id',
        'joinTable' => 'localidades_unidades'
    ]);
    //
}
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create')
        ->add('id', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table']);

    $validator
        ->add('status', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
        ->requirePresence('status', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('status');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('nome', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('nome');

    return $validator;
}
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['id']));
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['municipio_id'], 'Municipios'));
    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: localidades request data hasn't passed validation

Comment: Hi @NNem, thanks for helping me!
Yes, that's really odd. I'm passing just the `id` in both cases (`sistemas`and `localidades`). The first association is correctly patched, the full object is retrieved in the DB, no errors shown. The `localidades` behave differently: It creates a new object ("new" : true), without data and with validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the `belongsToMany('Unidades')` in `LocalidadesTable`

```
$this->belongsToMany('Unidades', [
    'foreignKey' => 'localidade_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'unidade_id',
    'joinTable' => 'localidades_unidades'
]);
```

Comment: You may have to delete the cache in tmp dir.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! I added the belongsToMany, cleared cache dir and restarted the cake server, but unfortunatelly nothing has changed regarding the problem.